# remove unwanted space in start of CSV file generated using PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, file-io, removing-whitespace

I am generating CSV file using PHP. What i am doing is

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo "mycontent";
exit;
```

It generates the CSV file with my content, but two extra spaces (tab spaces, i guess) are being added in the start of CSV content. I have used trim(), and other related functions to remove spaces, but it does not help.

Sample output (with spaces):

```
    first_column,second_column
first_data,second_data
```

but it should be:

```
first_column,second_column
first_data,second_data
```

Please help me how to remove these two extra spaces in the start of CSV file.

Comment: i have also used other methods of CSV generating like fputs, fputcsv, fopen, but all method add extra space in start

Comment: Need more substance to the question, as of now theres no way for us to try and fix it if we dont know what is wrong..?

Comment: thanks Tristan for your attention, what else do you need?

Comment: Your PHP must be outputting these characters. I'd guess they're whitespace in the PHP file, or perhaps a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (a BOM will very likely *look* like a couple of spaces in the output.) Unless you post your actual code, or at least a small, working example that actually reproduces the problem, it's unlikely we'll be able to help more than that.

Answer (score 12):

I had this exact same problem and finally found a solution after many hours of searching. Adding: ob_end_clean() after the header fixed it...

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.txt"');
ob_end_clean();
```

I had never used ob_end_clean() before but looks like it cleans up buffers and other things that seem to lead to a double whitespace at the beginning of files created for download in this way. I only found the solution as it was part of the code in a sample not related to this problem so hopefully someone in the future will stumble across this post, fix the problem and move on with their life!

Comment: technically can someone explains why this works? hahaha

Comment: Saved me hours.   All I did was upgrade from PHP 5.2 to 5.6 on one system and 7.4 on another, both had the extra space prefixed on a .zip download corrupting it.

Comment: Saved me hours too...thanks